# Is it good to include all js file and css file in the main page as AngularJS way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, single-page-application, angularjs-1.6

I work with AngularJS for several months, but I am still confused at the point: Is it good to include all JavaScript and CSS files in the main page the AngularJS way?

In my opinion, it may cause many conflicts when using many CSS and JS plugins. Also, the web browser loads too many files that may not be used on a specific page. Does this way cause some performance problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this way cause some performance problem?

AngularJS creed is based on [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application):

A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or web site that fits on a single web page with the goal of providing a user experience similar to that of a desktop application. In an SPA, either all necessary code – HTML, JavaScript, and CSS – is retrieved with a single page load.

Of course it may cost more in terms of performance at the launch of the application, but it will more fluid/user friendly after.

> In my opinion, it may cause many conflicts when i use many css, js
>   plugins file...

It should not create conflicts. But you have to be carefull when naming your CSS classes, JS files. A convenient way not to override CSS classes is to set prefixes on your classes: CSS classes for view 1 may have a prefix `v1-*`, classes used throughout the application do not need a prefix. This way you will know which CSS stand for (global or specific for a view). Also think about separate your CSS / JS in different files. [*Divide and conquer*](http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Divide-and-conquer-in-software-architecture)

I would suggest you to use standards ([here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) is a very blog for AngularJS guidelines).

Comment: It is useful and something is new for me. Thanks Mistalis.